# Ajax button not functioning in newly loaded form content - Drupal 7

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

I have got a module, where, when a user clicks on a link, I am loading a new form in a dialog, which has an Ajax-enabled submit button. In my dialog, I don't want the entire drupal header and footer, etc., to display. All I am displaying is, the contents of that new form. So my form is outputted via json like this:

```
$json['html'] = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('my_form'));
drupal_json_output($json);
```

Which works like I want, and only the form contents are displayed. However, when this happens, the submit button in that form, which is ajax-enabled, doesn't submit through ajax. Instead, it submits like a normal button and takes me to the same form on another page.

If I have the form being outputted and displayed normally, with the header and footers, like this:

```
$output = drupal_get_form('my_form');
return $output;
```

everything works just fine, and my submit button is 'ajax-enabled'.

I thought, maybe it was because I was loading the new content and the behaviors were not being attached to the these new form contents. So in my js file, I did this as well:

```
$('a.my_link', context).click(function() {
//processing done here
$('#my_modal_dialog').html(jsondata['html']);
}, "json");
Drupal.attachBehaviors($('#my_modal_dialog'));
```

That little addition, didn't fix the problem either. I am wondering as to why, if the form is outputted normally the button works as an ajax button, and when, only the form content is displayed, the ajax doesn't work.

Hoping someone will have the answer...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the problem solved and it can be found in the following link: [drupal.org/node/1517414](http://drupal.org/node/1517414).

Comment: Maybe you could reproduce the solution here, for when that link goes bad?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is indeed that the javascript isn't being applied to the new content, since it is run once after the page loads. Try using the `live()` method:

```
$('a.my_link', context).live("click", function() {
  ...
});
```

Note that the live() method seems to have been deprecated as of jQuery 1.7: http://api.jquery.com/live/

It seems to have been replaced by methods [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Comment: I tried using live() and on(), but neither worked.  I know it has to be something with applying the Drupal.behaviors/settings, wherein, the behaviors/settings will be applied to the new content as well.  I need to know what is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if `$` replaced with `jQuery`, maybe this help.

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with using $()

Comment: I have got the problem solved and it can be found in the following link:  http://drupal.org/node/1517414.